# Traversing recursively through a matrix in java to find the best path

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, matrix

I am trying to write some Java code that I will later translate into MIPS assembly. So I am trying to keep it as simple as possible. I need to traverse **diagonally down** a matrix, summing up the numbers, to find the highest sum path. I am completely lost on how to write this recursive method, any help will be much appreciated!

This is the code I've written so far, first being the main method, which creates the 'game board' and calls the method. The method then translates the given single array into a 2D array. Taking that 2d array and recursively finding the best path is what I am stuck on.

```
public class intro {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        int[] board = {10, 5, 3, 9, 6, 3, 1, 7, 10, 2, 9, 8, 4, 1, 11, 14, 18, 20, 13, 12};
        int max_rows = 4;
        int max_cols = 5;
        playCheckers newGame = new playCheckers(board, max_rows, max_cols);
        newGame.play();
    }
}
```

```
public class playCheckers {

    private int[] board;
    private int max_rows;
    private int max_cols;

    public playCheckers(int[] board, int max_rows, int max_cols){
        this.board = board;
        this.max_rows = max_rows;
        this.max_cols = max_cols;
    }

    public void play(){
        int[] sum = new int[max_cols];
        int[][] newArr = new int [max_rows][max_cols];
        int result = 0;
        int arrCount = 0;
        ///Turns single array into 2D array///
        for(int i=0; i < max_rows; i++){
            for(int j=0; j < max_cols; j++){
                newArr[i][j] = board[arrCount];
                arrCount++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("The max value is " + result + " starting at column " + col);
    }
}
```

Comment: How is it that you are looking for maximu-sum path when you only summing down the diagonal of matrix? If I understand correctly than that is just one and only one path, namely down the diagonal. Or is it that you are trying to sum up non-main diagonals as well?

Comment: So starting at a number in the top row, you can go diagonally left or right downwards. You'd go left or right depending on which number is higher/gets you the highest sum in the end. Then you would go to another number in the top row, and repeat the process. So like "zig-zagging" through the matrix.

Comment: But if I chose right in first step, then I can only choose right in all subsequent steps?

Comment: No, you can go left or right diag in each step downwards. 
Sorry I should have put that in the main question, my bad.

Comment: You know this is a problem with exponential complexity rigth?

Comment: uhhhh...noo? Sorry I'm still pretty new at this. 
Edit: I just know it needs to be recursive, but still simple enough that I can *attempt* to translate into MIPS assembly.